# Show tiles from other zoomlevel in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I'm trying to make offline maps with Leaflet.

For data saving, the user has an option to not save all the zoomlevels. By example the user has the zoomlevels:
- 15 and 17.

Now the problem is, when the user is zooming in from level 15 to 16.

How do I show the level 15 (or 17) layers on the zoom from 16?

Alternative is to skip the zoomlevel 16, but maybe there is another option?
I looked into the sourcecode from leaflet, but I can't figure it out.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zoutepopcorn/7a3xe/)

[Update Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zoutepopcorn/7a3xe/14/) with Plugin that skips the zoomlevel (by Ilja Zverev)

**HTML**

```
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="out"></div>
```

**JAVASCIPT**

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([52.084, 5.11], 15);
isNoZoomlevel = 16;

L.tileLayer('http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>',
    maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);


map.on('zoomend', function() {
    console.log("I zoomed to level " + map.getZoom());    
    if(map.getZoom() == isNoZoomlevel) {
        console.log("This offline zoomlevel does not excist");
        $("#out").html("This is no zoomlevel");
         // Howto replace the zoomlevel 16 with 17 or 15??   
    } else {
        $("#out").html("");
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
#map {
    height: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specially for you I've just made [LimitZoom plugin](https://github.com/Zverik/Leaflet.LimitZoom): just specify zoom levels in `zooms: [15, 17, ...]` options of `L.Map`.

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks for the nice plugin.

The only problem is that it don't show tiles from level 15 on zoomlevel 16. It just skips the zoomlevel 16. So when you have only 3 zoomlevels it zooms extreme... I'm gonna learn howto write a plugin. Maybe I can make a contribute to your github..

Comment: I want to make it something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/zoutepopcorn/7a3xe/17/

Comment: You're in luck, because I'm in experimenting mood :) See [Leaflet.ContinuousZoom plugin here](https://github.com/Zverik/Leaflet.LimitZoom). There is a link to a demonstration.

Comment: Awesome!!! So I have to try it with the offline tiles on my mobile app. I think it will work out, and I can accept the answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your example, this works for me

```
var prevZoom = 15;
map.on('zoomend', function() {

    if(map.getZoom() == isNoZoomlevel) {

        if(map.getZoom() > prevZoom) {
            map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1); // force zoomIn
        }
        if(map.getZoom() < prevZoom) {
            map.setZoom(map.getZoom() - 1); // force zoomOut
        }
    } 
    prevZoom = map.getZoom();
});
```